# Durett Example 3.2.4 Waiting for rare events

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to understand  an example in Durret's Probability theory textbook.

Let $X_p$ bet the number of trials needed to get a success in a sequence of independent trials with success probability $p$. Then

$$\mathbb{P}(X_p\ge n)=(1-p)^{n-1}$$

I don't understand how this is true shouldn't

$$\mathbb{P}(X_p\ge n)=\sum_{j=n}^{\infty}(1-p)^{j-1}$$

and then the example states that as $p\rightarrow 0$

$$\mathbb{P}(pX_p\ge x)\rightarrow\text{exp}(-x)$$

I am trying to make sense as to how they went from a discrete to a continuous random variable and concluded with the statement above

Comment: Do you see how he got $e^{-x}$, assuming that the passage to a continuous variable is legitimate?

Comment: @saulspatz I believe that they are simply using $\mathbb{P}(X_p>\frac{x}{p})=(1-p)^{\frac{x}{p}}\rightarrow \text{exp}(-x)$. The part I am missing is how they make that leap of evaluation $\mathbb{P}(X_p>\frac{x}{p})=(1-p)^{\frac{x}{p}}$ assuming what I have above is correct.

Comment: That's it, except that it should be $\mathbb{P}(X_p>\frac{x}{p})=(1-p)^{\frac{x}{p}\color{red}{-1}}\rightarrow \text{exp}(-x)$

Comment: @saulspatz But how are they able to make that leap from a discrete to a continuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability it takes you $\ge n$ coinflips to get heads is the same as the probability the first $n-1$ coinflips are tails. And that's just $(1-p)^{n-1}$ from independence. I think the formula you wrote down is motivated by $$ P(X_p\ge n) = \sum_{j=n}^\infty P(X_p=j),$$ but $P(X_p=j)$ is not $(1-p)^{j-1},$ it is $p(1-p)^{j-1},$ so we have $$ P(X_p\ge n) = (1-p)^{n-1}=p\sum_{j=n}^\infty (1-p)^{j-1}$$ and you can verify that the infinite sum does work out to make this equation true.

For the second part, $P(pX_p\ge x) = P(X_p\ge x/p)$, and $$ P(X_p\ge x/p) = (1-p)^{\lceil x/p\rceil-1}\to e^{-x}.$$ If you're worried about evaluating that limit with the ceiling function there, you can do it more carefully by observing $x/p\le \lceil x/p\rceil\le x/p+1 $ and using the squeeze theorem.